# IONIC: How convert an Object array into array?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, ionic-framework

I'm trying to convert an Object array into an array without use "let item of array" on html, I already google a lot but nothing that I find works.

Why I don't use loops? because I pretend to display data inside a page that comes from a liteSQL database, so all the data that I extract from that it's an Object and sure I can display the data without issues if I use a loop like "let item of array" but in this case I just want to show information on the HTML like **item.name** or **item.avatar**

Thanks in advance for any help, If you guys need more information please let me know.

The database have students so every array have: name, age, avatar, etc, so I try to show some like a profile after they tap the name on the list

EDIT:
[image: This is how the object array looks]

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can show how your object array looks like

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti done, I upload the image of how looks

Comment: Can you be more clear with a code example? Something like, "here's an example of the data, and here's an example of what I want to transform the data into". I know what objects are, and I know what arrays are, but I don't know what you mean by "object array".

Comment: @Wesley as I say I just want to convert the Object array to use it as values without the usage of a loop, usually I would use *ngFor="let item of array" as a way to use the array values, but I need a way to use it as a simple array just like I was using something like:

´item = [{ name: 'Name', age: 'Age', birthday: 'birthday'.. ....}]´

to use it on the HTML like **item.name**

Comment: It sounds like you have an array with an object in it, and you want to turn that into an array that just contains the objects values. Correct?

Comment: key and value: **item.name**, **item.age**, **item.birthday** etc but yes

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving from your server is an `array` of objects.

array of objects ->

```
[{
  key1:vlaue1,
  key2:value2
 },
 {
  key1:vlaue1,
  key2:value2
 }]
```

You refer the values here by using `array[0]['key1']`  `array[0]['key2']` and so on

In your case, you are receiving only one object in the array, so simply use `array[0].name` `array[0].age` and so on

Comment: I already try this before and I receive the error "ctx.item[0] it's undefined

Comment: In your question, the logged object, is that what `ctx` is? If yes, then use `ctx[0]` and not item

Comment: ctx doesn't exist on my code, that's displayed on the error console

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I actually found the solution by my self, I just need to use:

```
item: array = <array>{};
```

in order to use my object array as a simple array items without any loop on html